# Cannot login to bluemix with cf command

Tags: authentication, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I try to login to bluemix with the cf login command with my IBM sso ID but it "rejects my credentials".

Is it right that I should be able to login with my IBM ID (email address) and my sso password which I use to login to Bluemix?

Comment: You need to use the IBM ID password (different from the sso password). Also change the habit and use that combo to login to the Bluemix website, too.

Answer (score 4):

You need to log in with your external IBM.com ID.  If you do not have one or think you might have one head over to the Bluemix signup page, http://bluemix.net/registration.

Comment: Just to integrate, IBM internal ID doesn't work on cf cli



@han-van-gerwen: please accept jeff's answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the "right" creds, as stated above.

The following command line sequence works for me (and can even be scripted - hint, hint):

```
cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
cf login -u dtoczala@us.ibm.com -o dtoczala@us.ibm.com -s 'yourspacenamehere'
cf push yourappnamehere
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure that you are choosing the correct endpoint based on your region. If you account is in EU-GB, set you endpoint to https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net.

If you post the error details, it would help further.